# How to remove a large ugly space from my wordpress site?

Tags: themes

I'm sorry to ask such a simple question. You would think I would be able to figure it out on my own, but I've been up all night running in circles trying to remove a simple space from my website's homepage.

Site is: ThePoint.news

The space is between the header/social media links and "Trending Posts"... You can't miss it.

My brain is fried from trying to get rid of this. I've looked at the code in the template, I've downloaded "space removing plugins", I've tried tweaking the theme.. everything. Yet I can not solve this simple problem.

Any help would be so appreciated. Thanks...

Image below of the hideous nuisance:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is coming from an empty div with ID "subfeatures". If you don't want this div you can remove it by changing the code or by using css

div#subfeatures {
    display: none;
}

Comment: glad to know it worked for you.. always happy to help